# Azure Data Factory API call throws payload limit error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are performing Copy Activity with API Rest Url as data source and ADLS Gen2 as sink. The pipeline works in most cases and sporadically throws below error. We have nested pipeline to loop through multiple REST API request parameters and make call within **forEach** activity.

Error displayed in ADF monitor-

```
Error Code - 2200
Failure Type - User Configuration issue   
Details - The payload including configurations on activity/dataset/linked service is too large. Please check if you have settings with very large value and try to reduce its size.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error message: The payload including configurations on
> activity/dataSet/linked service is too large. Please check if you have
> settings with very large value and try to reduce its size.

**Cause:** The payload for each activity run includes the activity configuration, the associated dataset(s), and linked service(s) configurations if any, and a small portion of system properties generated per activity type. The limit of such payload size is 896 KB as mentioned in the Azure limits documentation for Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics.

**Recommendation:** You hit this limit likely because you pass in one or more large parameter values from either upstream activity output or external, especially if you pass actual data across activities in control flow. Check if you can reduce the size of large parameter values or tune your pipeline logic to avoid passing such values across activities and handle it inside the activity instead.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#payload-is-too-large

Comment: with this solution we were able to copy but need to limit payload